# SAP GUI script not recording steps

Tags: python, win32com, sap-gui

I am automating an extraction from SAP using win32COM on python.

I already made a similar program, but now I'm getting a lot of new problems.

I'm using the native SAP GUI scripting which saves .vbs file, and I use the Ids in the Python.

But my script only record the steps until the selection of the transaction.
Stopping on this page:
[image]

After this step the commands don't appear at the script file.

In Python, even if I try to select a page element I get an exception.

Here is my code:

```
pathname = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"

subprocess.Popen(pathname)
time.sleep(8)


SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    exit()

application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    SapGuiAuto = None
    exit() 
    
connection = application.OpenConnection("P08 [BC_P08]", True)
if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    application = None
    SapGuiAuto = None
    exit()
    
session = connection.Children(0)
if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
    connection = None
    application = None
    SapGuiAuto = None
    exit()

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").text = "430"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "*******"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "*******"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").text = "PT"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "ke24"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)          # Until here everything is OK

# Until here the steps are showed on the SAP script, but the tool stops recording after this

# I tried the following steps to continue the automation, without success
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()          # This line rises an exception
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[17]").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtV-LOW").text = "LATAM_FIN_ARG"
```

The Error message is:
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in findById(self, *args)

com_error: (-2147417851, 'The server raised an exception.', None, None)

How can I continue to select a variant and save the extraction as .csv or.xls?

Comment: The error happens in `findById` so I guess there's no element in the screen with the given ID. Please debug your script so that to know which line is concerned. Your question title is misleading, do you mean "recording" or "playing"?

Comment: No, I mean recording too. The scripting tool  that runs on SAP GUI records the process until the page that I show. The line which throws exception is just my attempt to continue the process that SAP didn't record.
Edit: There are any other way to discover the IDs that not this tool?

Comment: Yes. You may write your own code to get all the IDs. There are also 2 graphical tools which both use SAP GUI Scripting, one by [SAP](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1441550/E), one by [Stefan Schnell](https://tracker.stschnell.de/index.htm).

Comment: That's weird that the SAP GUI Scripting recorder stops recording. It's worth investigating the cause...